# problems when I run my java code in vscode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I think I have set the `task.json` and `launch.json` right.

`tasks.json`

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "Compile Java",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "javac ${file}",
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }
]
}
```

Here is `launch.json`

```
{
// 使用 IntelliSense 了解相关属性。 
// 悬停以查看现有属性的描述。
// 欲了解更多信息，请访问: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Java",
        "type": "java",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "externalConsole": false,
        "preLaunchTask": "Compile Java",
        "jdkPath": "${env:JAVA_HOME}/bin",
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "startupClass": "${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        "classpath": [
            "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home/lib",
            ".",
            "${fileDirname}"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Java Console App",
        "type": "java",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "preLaunchTask": "Compile Java",
        "jdkPath": "${env:JAVA_HOME}/bin",
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "startupClass": "${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        "classpath": [
            "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home/lib",                
            ".",
            "${fileDirname}"
        ],
        "externalConsole": true
    }
]
}
```

But when I click the debug button, nothing happened, and there is nothing in the debug console:

[image]

and the pause button on the top, I click it but nothing happened.
then I set a breakpoint but it looks like trying to get into the program like this:

[image: i'm almost crazy]